# How to push helm chart from Jfrog artifactory to Azure container registry

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I have my Helm chart hosted in a **Jfrog artifactory**. My helm chart can be accessed using:
http://repository.test.com:8181/artifactory/compress-files/abc/abc-1.2-helm.tgz

The expectation is to create an Azure container registry repository **abc-1.2** and eventually my AKS pods will be created using this repository. The organization has been doing this since quite sometime but haven't documented how this was done in the past.

I have read all the Microsoft articles and online articles. All the articles talk about creating a helm chart, packaging and pusing to ACR which is easy.

This scenario is specific where the requirement is to:

1. Create ACR repository using Helm chart on Jfrog artifactory.
2. Configure rolling update to existing PODs so that the PODs now use new container repository.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For helm3, charts in ACR is like a repository.

**Plan 1:**
[az acr import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-import) CLI command should just work like you import an image:

```
az acr import \
  --name MyContainer \
  --source Jfrogtest.jfrog.io/demo-sample:2.0.0.83 \
  --image demo-sample:2.0.0.83 \
  --username \
  --password
```

OR

```
az acr import -n XXXX --source helm/hello-world:v2 -t helm/hello-world:v2 -r /subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXX/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/XXXX
```

**Plan 2:**
If the above steps fails, alternatively you could leverage the [docker pull](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) and [docker push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) commands.